# How can i find Facebook Open Graph Activity Plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I have developed a website that uses Facebook Open Graph methods. But when i submit it facebook returned me with a message that i have to put something in my website like the image below

[image: Social Plugin]

Where can i find a plugin like this?

I only find this one ; https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/
but it's useless.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no plugin like this currently available. You have to develop one yourself.

You should be using facebook connect and keeping track of all this actions as well as submitting them to graph API. If so, you only need to ad this on/off button and activity log.

This way the user has control over his activity...